# Find slope (angle) of each line of the image

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, hough-transform

I have to calculate a slope (or an angle) of every single detectable line of the image. And even to detect the changes of the slope of the line, if it is possible.
I've performed 2D Fourier and I know a neighborhood averege angle at every area (sets of 64x64px). I even try a Hough transform, but neither sobel nor prewitt edge detection seems to detect these lines appropriately.
Please note that some of the lines are crossing each other, and some aren't straight.
Is there a method to detect the slope of each line? Or to detect these lines in order to perform an usefull Hough transform?

If you need the full image I can upload it somewhere.

[Image](http://i56.tinypic.com/2uohto8.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Greets Adamek,

I hope it is not too late. Here some quick ideas:

1) Using Hough trafo to detect lines is a good idea as a first step
2) Second step would be some kind of labeling to really know what lines there are. The most difficult problem to address is probably how to determine start and end of lines and seperate potentially connected ones. Search for the labeling keyword in this context, that should give some results.
3) Afterwards, having end and startpoint, I would
  a) calculate for each line a regression line if you need more exact data in further analysis
  b) just compute slope and intercept via f(x)=mx+n, where m is the slope and n the intercept. Given two points in 2D this is easily done as follows:

```
slope = (yRight - yLeft)/(xRight - xLeft);
m_oIntercept = ((yLeft - slope*xLeft) + (yRight - slope*xRight))*0.5;
```

and don't forget to test for (xRight-xLeft) < eps before to avoid zero division.

Hope that helps,
G.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not too late.

Comment: I performed earlier the labelling and visualization on input picture of these detected lines. So I know, that not every line is detected, and I know, that it is not a Hough transform failure. It is all about the preliminary operations (histogram  equalization, sobel or prewitt edge detection, ...). Nevertheless thenk you for your attempt to solve my problem.